# What age would an off-worlder start taking the spice Melange?

Tags: dune, age

In the *Dune* series by Frank Herbert, at what age would people not from Arrakis (eg. Members of a Great House/aristocracy or the rich) start taking Melange? As it has geriatric properties to extend the life span of the user, would you wait until post 20s so you prolong at a mature stage or if you started say pre-teen would you still go through puberty at a normal rate?

If I remember correctly Paul Atreides hadn't taken​ Melange before arriving on Arrakis and he is 15 at the start of the series.

Comment: IIRC, Spice wasn't commonly taken by people that weren't training to be navigators, no?  I expect there might be some recreational use in the upper class. but I had the impression it was a thing people knew about, but did not use.

Comment: @VBartilucci yes the Guild use it as do the Bene Gesserit but most of not all of the Great Houses were using it mainly for its life prolonging qualities.

Comment: Given that Fremen children and other children on Arrakis develop normally, it's most likely a matter of expense, and not being necessary. Agree that late 20s, early 30s would be when consumption would begin.

Comment: Whenever they get left alone at home for the first time and find their parents stash?

Comment: This is never covered in the book series, so there is no canonical answer.    But there is the line "on some worlds a handful could buy a house."  This gives us some idea of price, and thus availability to a common user.  But is still very unclear, given that on our world the price of a house can range a thousandfold from one country to the next.